# When I set this to a variable, it changes the value. Does anyone know why?

Tags: java

```
int temp = a1.charAt(num);
System.out.println(a1.charAt(num));
System.out.println(temp);
```

(a1 is a string that contains 6 8 1 5 ...)

(num is 0)

the output is:

6

54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(int)'6' == 54
'6' == (char)54
'6' == (char)0x36
```

cf. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

`System.out.println` has different overloads for parameters of type `int` (prints the numeric/ordinal representation of the value) and for parameters of type `char` (prints the character representation of the ordinal value).

Answer (score 2):

It is because the  `.chatAt()` method returns a char and you are storing it in an integer variable. Hence, it is stored as it's ASCII value.

6 in ASCII is 54.

Link - [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Answer (score 1):

ASCII value of 6 is 54.

When you a1.charAt(0) it prints character 6 from the string = 6815.

But when you assign char 6 to int, then it prints its equivalent ASCII value, which is 54.